# test failing to match correct intent component

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I am having trouble using espresso intents to test an activity which is started using an intent. The execution flow works in the following way

1. In the Main Activity, you click a button
2. The button executes an AsyncTask to fetch some data
3. onPostExecute of the AsyncTask, I create an intent add fetched data as Intent Extra and then start a new activity which displays the fetched data.

The code which creates the intent and starts the the new activity looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra(key, result);
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This all works when I run the app. As far as testing using espresso the test code looks like this:

```
...

@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mIntentTestRule =
                           new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false);

@Test
public void testMainActivityAsyncTask() {
    // Find view with button
    onView(withText(R.string.button_text)).perform(click());

    // Ensure correct intent setup
    intended(allOf(
            hasComponent(NewActivity.class.getName()),
            hasExtraWithKey(key),
            toPackage("com.example.espresso")));

    // Ensure appropriate activity and view is launched
    onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.expected_view),                                                   
            withText(isEmptyOrNullString())));

    // Let it go
    Intents.release();
}
```

When I run the test, the test fails with these errors (summarized for brevity):

... Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:
-Intent { cmp=com.example.doingstuff/com.example.espresso.NewActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.example.doingstuff]], extras:[Bundle[{akey=aVal]])

A few questions here:
1. Why is the cmp value in the error message preceded by the package name of my MainActivity class i.e. "com.example.doingstuff/" that may be part of my problem
2. Is the error message above suggesting that it found an intent i.e. "com.example.doingstuff/com.example.espresso.NewActivity" but it did not match what I was expecting?

I have done a lot googling without help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try removing one intended condition at a time to see which one(s) are causing the failure, and let us know

Comment: hi, any answer for this? :)